# Windows 7 installer wont boot after creating partition for Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, partition, windows

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro (13 inch Mid 2012) running OS X 10.7.5
I'm using a USB drive to create the boot disk, and I also downloaded the drivers needed from the apple website. 
After creating the partition and restarting, the system tells me that there is no bootable drive available. I try holding the option key and then selecting the windows partition and then it shows the same screen.

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The most common Issue when installing bootcamp windows

Causes: 
Failed to detect USB3.0 drive after reboot

Solution:
Use a **USB2.0** drive to create windows install disk instead of USB 3.0 drives.

Or you can inject usb3.0 driver into the installer using Dism++

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my iMac 2011. Your MacBook Pro won't boot from your USB stick because it has a Superdrive and only accepts alternative booting from there. Either use Windows install DVD or disconnect the Superdrive manually. Lots of tutorials on youtube how to do that.

Comment: This is completely incorrect.  Intel based Macs could boot from Macs that had 10.4.5 or later (roughly 2006).  However, the boot medium must be formatted GUID.  Please refer to this [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201663)